# Node.js - 'ReferenceError: body is not defined' when connecting to server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating my first web application backend for a movie review site but I've become stuck as I'm getting a ReferenceError: body is not defined error. Here is the code I've written so far:

index.js

```js
import app from './server.js'                       
import mongodb from "mongodb"                       
import dotenv from "dotenv"                         
import MoviesDAO from './dao/moviesDAO.js'          
                                                    
                                                    
import ReviewsDAO from './dao/reviewsDAO.js'

async function main(){                              
                                                    
     dotenv.config()                                                         
    
const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(             
process.env.MOVIEREVIEWS_DB_URI,
    {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology:true}    
    )
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8000           
     try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.connect()                      
        await MoviesDAO.injectDB(client)            
                                                    
        await ReviewsDAO.injectDB(client)

        app.listen(port, () =>{                     
            console.log('server is running on port:'+port);        
        })                                                          

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);                                                       
        process.exit(1)                             
    } 
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

server.js

```js
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import movies from './api/movies.route.js'

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.use("/api/v1/movies", movies)
app.use('*', (req,res)=>{
     res.status(404).json(
          {error: "requested path not found"})
})

export default app
```

package.json

```js
{"name":"backend",
"version":"1.0.0",
"description":"",
"main":"index.js",
"type":"module",
"scripts":{"test":"echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"},
"author":"",
"license":"ISC",
"dependencies":{
    "babel":"^6.23.0",
    "cors":"^2.8.5",
    "dotenv":"^10.0.0",
    "express":"^4.17.2",
    "mongodb":"^4.2.2"
    }
}
```

movies.route.js

```js
import express from 'express'                                       
import MoviesController from './movies.controller.js'               
import ReviewsController from './reviews.controller.js'

const router = express.Router() // get access to the express router

router.route('/').get(MoviesController.apiGetMovies)
router.route("/id/:id").get(MoviesController.apiGetMoviesById)
router.route("/ratings").get(MoviesController.apiGetRatings)

router
    .route("/review")
    .post(ReviewsController.apiPostReview)
    .put(ReviewsController.apiUpdateReview)
    .delete(ReviewsController.apiDeleteReview)

export default router
```

moviesDAO

```js
import mongodb from "mongodb"
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId  

let movies

export default class MoviesDAO {
    static async injectDB(conn) {
        if(movies) {
            return
        }
        try {
            movies = await conn.db(process.env.MOVIEREVIEWS_NS)
                        .collection('movies')
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.error(`Unable to connect in moviesDAO: ${e}`)   
        }
    }
    
    static async getMovies({
        filters = null,
        page = 0,
        moveisPerPage = 20,
    } = {}) {
        let query
        if (filters) {
            if ("title" in filters) {
                query = { $text: { $search: filters['title']}}
            } else if("rated" in filters) {
                query = {"rated": { $eq: filters['rated']}}
            }
        }

        let cursor
        try {
            cursor = await movies
                        .find(query)
                        .limit(moveisPerPage)
                        .skip(moveisPerPage * page)
            const movieList = await cursor.toArray()
            const totalNumMovies = await movies.countDocuments(query)
            return {movieList, totalNumMovies}
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`)
            return {movieList: [], totalNumMovies: 0}
        }
    }

    static async getRatings(){
        let ratings = []
        try{
            ratings = await movies.distinct("rated")
            return ratings
        }
        catch(e){
            console.error(`unable to get ratings, $(e)`)
            return ratings
        }
    }

    static async getMovieById(id){
        try{
            return await movies.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        _id: new ObjectId(id),
                    }
                }   ,
                { $lookup:
                {
                    from: 'reviews',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: 'movie_id',
                    as: 'reviews',
                }
            }
            ]).next()
        }
        catch(e){
            console.error(`something went wrong in getMovieByID: ${e}`)
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

movies.controller.js

```js
import MoviesDAO from "../dao/moviesDAO.js";

export default class MoviesController {

    static async apiGetMovies(req, res, next) {                     
        const moveisPerPage = req.query.moveisPerPage ?             
                parseInt(req.query.moveisPerPage) : 20              
        const page = req.query.page ? parseInt(req.query.page) : 0  

        let filters = {}
        if(req.query.rated){
            filters.rated = req.query.rated
        }
        else if(req.query.title) {
            filters.title = req.query.title
        }

        const { movieList, totalNumMovies } = await MoviesDAO.getMovies
                                                ({filters, page, moveisPerPage})
        
        let response = {
            movies: movieList,
            page: page,
            filter: filters,
            entries_per_page: moveisPerPage,
            total_results: totalNumMovies,
        }
        res.json(response)
    }

    static async apiGetMoviesById(req, res, next) {
        try{
            let id = req.params.id || {}
            let movie = await MoviesDAO.getMovieById(id)
            if(!movie){
                res.status(404).json({ error: "not found"})
                return
            }
            res.json(movie)
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(`api, ${e}`)
            res.status(500).json({error: e})
        }
    }
    static async apiGetRatings(req, res, next){
        try{
            let propertyTypes = await MoviesDAO.getRatings()
            res.json(propertyTypes)
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(`api,${e}`)
            res.status(500).json({error: e})
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error when I try running my server:

```js
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server index.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server index.js`
/Users/ashleymccann/Desktop/Dissertation/movie-reviews/backend/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:81
      var first = firstchar(body)
                            ^

ReferenceError: body is not defined
    at Function.json (/Users/ashleymccann/Desktop/Dissertation/movie-reviews/backend/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:81:29)
    at file:///Users/ashleymccann/Desktop/Dissertation/movie-reviews/backend/server.js:9:17
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)

Node.js v18.15.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Using Mac OS

Tried multiple ways to troubleshoot on other stackoverflow posts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you.